# Using mutate() to create a column that is the total of other columns

Tags: r

First, I promise I looked for the answer first. I only started learning R yesterday and the question very basic. So either it's too basic to have been asked or I don't realize I'm reading the answer.

Basically, this is the task in this exercise (don't worry, it's not a test):

> You can also use the`mutate()` function to make changes to your columns. Let's say you wanted to create a new column that summed up all the adults, children, and babies on a reservation for the total number of people. Modify the code chunk below to create that new column:

```r
example_df <- bookings_df %>%
  mutate(guests = )

head(example_df)
```

There are three columns ("adults", "children", and "babies") whose values I want to add in the new column called "guests". So i tried

```r
example_df <- bookings_df %>%
  mutate(example_df, guests = c("adults", "children", "babies"))

head(example_df)
```

And of course, it comes back with an error "`guests` must be size 119390 or 1, not 3."

Now, up until this point, I haven't learned any advanced functions. So the answer is going to be something extremely basic for a first week R student.

Help?

Comment: mutate can also be used to create a new column.  `example_df <- bookings_df %>% mutate(guests = sum(adults, children, babies))` might work.  For future reference, it is best practice to provide some sample data so those who help you don't have to do as much work.  For that, look into `dput()`

Comment: @TTS you should add `rowwise()` before summation. Otherwise, you will get a single value indicating the total of all columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data in the "adults", "children", and "babies" columns are the numeric counts of how many there are for each reservation, here are two simple solutions:

```r
# solution 1: use the addition operator
example_df <- bookings_df %>% mutate(guests = adults + children + babies)

# solution 2: use the rowwise() and sum() functions
example_df <- bookings_df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(guests = sum(adults, children, babies))
```

Note that the `rowwise()` in *Solution 2* allows the summation performed through the `sum()` function to be row-wise. If `rowwise()` is not specified for *Solution 2*, the `sum()` command will sum everything from all three columns together and provide the single answer (total sum) for all rows in the column `guest`.

**Explaining the error in your attempt**

`c("adults", "children", "babies")` in your attempt outputs the three words that you typed as three separate outputs. Thus, you received the error, "`guests` must be size 119390 or 1, not 3." It can be 119390 outputs because `bookings_df` has 119390 rows so it needs that many outputs, or 1 output so that all the outputs in the new column are the same.

`c()` also does not perform the mathematical addition of those three words. Run `?c` in R for a helpful description on how to use `c()`.

The quotations around the items `"adults"`, `"children"`, and `"babies"` further make those items as just words, or character class items. That means that the three words do not refer to columns in your data frame (though there is a longer roundabout way to make the character words refer to the column names in the data frame with other functions, that's likely beyond the scope of your exercise here).

Comment: The second code (`guests = sum(...)`) is going to calculate a single value and repeat it for every row in the frame. While it's a valid "statistic" in the pure sense, I wonder if the OP and/or intent of this answer is to more display the `+`-based answer, providing row-wise sums.

Comment: The first one is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!
As an aside, solution #2 returned all NAs.  Not sure if the reason relates to @r2evans 's comment, but for my education, could one of you explain to me why it would do that? It seems to me sum() should work there too, no?

Comment: (1) If _any_ value in any of those columns is `NA`, then you cannot get a sum without also specifying `na.rm=TRUE` to ignore them. Think of it this way: an `NA` values really means *"it could be anything"*. When all numbers are non-`NA`, then `sum(.)` on those numbers is well defined. However, if anything is "it could be anything", then the sum also "could be anything" (inf, negative inf, 0, 42, who knows). (2) `sum(.)` in a `mutate` call is almost never what is needed; the exception is when `rowwise()` or `group_by(.)` is used preceding the mutate call.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was negligent and didn't check the output when I posted. I provided a correction to my Solution 2. As @r2evans described, if you have any missing values or `NA`, then the `sum()` would return `NA`.  You may specify the parameter `na.rm=TRUE` in `sum()` (i.e., `sum(..., na.rm=TRUE)`) to ignore missing values.

Comment: But a word of caution when using `sum(..., na.rm=TRUE)`: the amount of data that you sum together may not be the same for every row. E.g., If Row 1 reports 20 guests in a child's birthday party and Row 2 reports 1 guest in another child's party, it may be because the number of children in the second party was not reported (`NA` value). We cannot confirm from the data whether it was a very small party or a very big party with 100 children because we do not have the data.

Comment: Other choices: `bookings_df %>% mutate(guests = rowSums(cbind(adults, children, babies)))` or `bookings_df %>% mutate(guests = rowSums(across(c("adults", "children", "babies"))))`. If there are many columns to be sum, the use of `across()` is flexible because it supports *tidy selections*, and it makes the character words refer to the column names in the data frame.